# What are perfected grounds of appeal?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, definition

According to [Julian Assange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Assange)'s anti extradition campaign, in late August his lawyers had filed their "perfected grounds of appeal". Just what does it mean for the grounds to be perfected?

Comment: Does it not just mean that they believe that they will be successful?

Comment: I doubt it. If the past in the case is anything to go by I don't think they would dare to foretell or believe in any outcome they're just doing the best they can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Julian Assange's current litigation is an appeal to the High Court, pursuant to [section 108](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/41/section/108) of the [*Extradition Act 2003*](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/41), against the Home Secretary's extradition order of 17 June 2022. The procedure for extradition appeals to the High Court is set out in [section 3 of Part 50](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/part/50/crossheading/7) of the [*Criminal Procedure Rules 2020*](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759).

[Rule 50.20](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/rule/50.20) requires Assange to apply for leave to appeal by filing an appeal notice which identifies his grounds of appeal. There is also a requirement to file skeleton arguments under [Practice Direction 50E](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/924052/crim-practice-directions-XI-other-proceedings-2015.pdf#page=20) in [Division XI](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/924052/crim-practice-directions-XI-other-proceedings-2015.pdf) of the *Criminal Practice Directions 2015*.

[Rule 50.30](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/759/rule/50.30) provides for an extradition appeal to be determined in appropriate cases by a [divisional court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisional_Court_(England_and_Wales)). That is what happened in the last appeal, *United States of America v Assange* [[2021] EWHC 3313 (Admin)](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Admin/2021/3313.html). The "[specialist court](https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/administrative-court) within the [King's Bench Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Court_of_Justice#Queen%27s_Bench_Division) of the High Court" which determined that case is known as the [Administrative Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Court_(England_and_Wales)).

The Administrative Court is quite similar to the [Court of Appeal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_of_Appeal_(England_and_Wales)) and its senior members [sit on both courts](https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/who-are-the-judiciary/judges/coa-judges/). The last appeal was determined by the Lord Chief Justice and a Lord Justice of Appeal. So, it would not be surprising if the orders made for case management of this Administrative Court proceeding adopted the practice of the Court of Appeal.

The practice of "perfection of grounds of appeal" is described in [section A8](https://www.criminalbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/The-Court-of-Appeal-Division-Guide-to-Commencing-Proceedings-1.pdf#page=11) of the [*Court of Appeal Criminal Division Guide to Commencing Proceedings*](https://www.criminalbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/The-Court-of-Appeal-Division-Guide-to-Commencing-Proceedings-1.pdf) (July 2021). In that jurisdiction, perfected grounds "consist of a fresh document
which supersedes the original grounds of appeal and contains *inter alia* references by page number and letter (or paragraph number) to all relevant passages in the transcript," which may not be available when the grounds are first prepared.

[Practice Direction 50A](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/924052/crim-practice-directions-XI-other-proceedings-2015.pdf#page=6) emphasises the importance of expedition in extradition appeals, especially "where the issues are such that further information from the requesting authority or state is needed." It is likely that the case management orders made in Assange's appeal allowed him to file some initial grounds of appeal and later "perfect" them, possibly after receiving documents that were not available when the grounds were first lodged, or a grant of leave to appeal.

This accords with the normal use of the verb "to perfect" in legal contexts (eg. the perfection of a judgment or security interest), which the Oxford English Dictionary defines as:

> To complete or finish successfully; to carry through, accomplish. In early use also: † to bring to fulfilment or full development (*obsolete*). Now chiefly *Law* and *Finance*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139581/discussion-on-answer-by-sjy-what-are-perfected-grounds-of-appeal).

Answer (score 5):

"Perfected" does not, as far as I have been able to establish, have a specific legal meaning in England and Wales.

In the absence of such, the convention is to use the normal meaning of the word; usually by reference to the Oxford English Dictionary which (unfortunately) is now behind a paywall.

However, [Merrian Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/perfected) includes these synonyms:

> completed, finished

Which, without knowing the context in which it was used, seem to be the most likely candidates.

Comment: As I understand it (not a lawyer!), the process broadly goes: (i) Appellant files their initial appeal paperwork; (ii) This gets sent to the respondent, who files a response; (iii) appellant and respondent may negotiate to clarify precisely what they agree on and what they're are arguing about; (iv) appellant files final 'perfected' grounds of appeal; (v) court hearing.